# Получить сумму свойств (price) объекта значения ключей которого также представляют из себя объекты

Tags: javascript

```
var fruits = {
    'apple': {
        'color': 'green',
        'sort': 'Granny Smith',
        'Country': 'Russia',
        'price': 68
    },
    'orange': {
        'color': 'orange',
        'sort': 'Valencia',
        'country': 'Spain',
        'price': 100.99
    },
    'pear': {
        'color': 'red',
        'sort': 'Conference',
        'country': 'Cyprus',
        'price': 120.59
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызов [`Object.values(fruits)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) преобразует объект в массив его свойств

и при помощи свертки ([`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)) этого массива можно получить сумму вложенных свойств:

```js
var fruits = {
    'apple': {
        'color': 'green',
        'sort': 'Granny Smith',
        'Country': 'Russia',
        'price': 68
    },
    'orange': {
        'color': 'orange',
        'sort': 'Valencia',
        'country': 'Spain',
        'price': 100.99
    },
    'pear': {
        'color': 'red',
        'sort': 'Conference',
        'country': 'Cyprus',
        'price': 120.59
    }
};

let c = Object.values(fruits).reduce((a,v) => a + v.price, 0)
console.log(c)
```